# play framework secure module performance

Tags: database, performance, security, playframework, playframework-1.x

i am using play framework version 1.2.5
i added the security model to my application . 
to verify my view's to hide some html menus according to user permissions.
i will also verify user logged etc.  (my current question in about the view)
i used the check method in the Security class like this

```
static boolean check(String profile) {
    LicenseType license = LicenseType.valueOf(profile);
    User user = User.find("byEmail", connected()).first();
    return user.hadLicense(license);
}
```

and in my template for example i do this

```
<html><body>
        #{secure.check "ADMIN"}
             <a href="link-to-admin-page" >
        #{/secure.check}
        .... some html 
        #{secure.check "EDIT"}
              <div>some html here </div>
        #{/secure.check}
        .... some html 
        #{secure.check "ADD"}
              <div>some html here </div>
        #{/secure.check}

</body></html>
```

my question is like this .
dose this case means, that a single view like this will access the database 4 times 
for selecting the user by the email .
just to check security ?

thank you .

Comment: can u help me understand this please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it does mean that the database is accessed for each check (although JPA might give you a cached entry - not sure there).

To avoid this you can cache the result on a per-request basis in

Request.args

Comment: dose placing the user license in the renderArgs using the @before method, and then checking it via Security.check will be a faster solution ?

Comment: now i am using cache (playframework memCache) for storing the user license, do u think its a good practice ?

Answer (score 0):

from the code sample you provided, it appears the user is already login. so i will suggest that you store the user license variable in session and then have a static method to do the comparison. You can equally store the license in a cache(memcache)

E.g.

```
static boolean check(String profile){   
        LicenseType license = LicenseType.valueOf(profile);       
        return User.hadLicense(license, connectedLicense());  
   }
```

NB: connectedLicense() - is the license of the user store during login.